# How to use sql query withpivot () into entityframework core 5.0

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
SELECT BuildingID,
       BuildingName,

       [-1] AS 'In Active',
       [0]  'Booked',
       [1]  'Occupied',
       [2]  'Vacant',
       [3]  'Temporary Booked',
       [4]  'Under Clearance',
       [5]  'Under Construction',
       [6]  'Reserved',
       [7]  'Temporary Leased',
       [8]  'Paid Booked',
       [9]  'Booking Payment Pending',

       Total=(SELECT Sum(TB.total_count)
              FROM   (VALUES([-1]),([0]),([1]),([2]),([3]),([4]),([5]),([6]),([7]),([8]),([9])) AS TB(total_count))

FROM   (SELECT b.buildingid,
               b.BuildingName,
               f.FacStatusID,
               f.FacilityNo
        FROM   Facility AS f
               INNER JOIN FacilityBuilding b
                       ON f.BuildingID = b.BuildingID
        WHERE  FacilityTypeID =1
               AND FacilitySubTypeID = @facilitySubTypeId and f.BuildingID=@buildingId) AS SourceTable
       PIVOT ( Count(FacilityNo)
             FOR FacStatusId IN ([-1],[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]) ) AS pivottable
ORDER  BY BuildingID;
```

[image]

I need to either convert this query in entity framework or use this stored procedure there. I don't have any entity in my db context related to this result. But I have separate entities such as facilities and facilityBuildings where buildingId is the primary key and serves as foreign key in facilities table
I have attached the screenshot too of the desired output.
please help me with how we can use this query for getting the desired attached output using entity framework core 5.0

Comment: Use Dapper, not EF.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ, as in SQL the alternative form for this query is a conditional aggregate query, so something like:

```
var q = from facility in db.Set<Facility>()
        where facility.FacilityTypeId == 1
        where facility.FacilitySubTypeId == subtype
        where facility.FacilityBuilding.BuildingId == buildingId
        group facility by facility.FacStatusId into byStatus
        select new
        {
            BuildingId = byStatus.Max(g => g.FacilityBuilding.BuildingId),
            BuildingName = byStatus.Max(g => g.FacilityBuilding.BuildingName),
            Booked = byStatus.Count(f => f.FacStatusId == -1),
            Occupied = byStatus.Count(f => f.FacStatusId == 0),
            Vacant = byStatus.Count(f => f.FacStatusId == 1),
            TemporaryBooked = byStatus.Count(f => f.FacStatusId == 2),
            Total = byStatus.Count()
        };
```

translates to

```
  SELECT MAX([f1].[BuildingId]) AS [BuildingId], MAX([f1].[BuildingName]) AS [BuildingName], COUNT(CASE
      WHEN [f].[FacStatusId] = -1 THEN 1
  END) AS [Booked], COUNT(CASE
      WHEN [f].[FacStatusId] = 0 THEN 1
  END) AS [Occupied], COUNT(CASE
      WHEN [f].[FacStatusId] = 1 THEN 1
  END) AS [Vacant], COUNT(CASE
      WHEN [f].[FacStatusId] = 2 THEN 1
  END) AS [TemporaryBooked], COUNT(*) AS [Total]
  FROM [Facility] AS [f]
  LEFT JOIN [FacilityBuilding] AS [f0] ON [f].[FacilityBuildingId] = [f0].[FacilityBuildingId]
  LEFT JOIN [FacilityBuilding] AS [f1] ON [f].[FacilityBuildingId] = [f1].[FacilityBuildingId]
  WHERE (([f].[FacilityTypeId] = 1) AND ([f].[FacilitySubTypeId] = @__subtype_0)) AND ([f0].[BuildingId] = @__buildingId_1)
  GROUP BY [f].[FacStatusId]
```